# Html entities like &euro; is not converted to its symbol in CSV conversion

Tags: php, html, csv

I have used CSV parser from http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/, to export my reports to CSV in PHP. I have displayed Sales Total value in `&euro;XXXX.XX`, in browser as well as in Excel(After exporting), displayed with the Euro symbol.

But in CSV, instead of Euro symbol, its showing the code `&euro;` only.

How can I export that `&euro;` to it's corresponding symbol to CSV.

Thanks in advance.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

This was the only thing that cleanly fixed it for me

```
 html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'utf-8')
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use `html_entity_decode()` on the strings before writing them to file, which will find all html entities and replace them with their actual symbol.

`html_special_chars()` and `html_special_chars_decode()` only works on a few html entities, like `&gt;` and `&lt;`, while `htmlentities()` and `html_entity_decode()` works on all of them.

Alternatively, you could just do a string replace (`str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` or whatever) for `&euro;` to replace with `€`.

Then Try:

`str_replace('&euro;','€',$valuebeingexported);`

Comment: @A.C.Balaji That's odd.  It should.  Try what I just added to the end.

Comment: still didn't work. the only way I got it to work is in my answer

Comment: I found that html_entity_decode() only working for entities with semi-colon, like &#x24; but not working for entities without, ie &#x24, which legal in browser.

Answer (score 1):

According to me Excel has some problems displaying CSV-files with unicode characters.You can try once below :

use `fputcsv()` with `utf-8` handling.

something like below :

```
$handler = fopen("php://output", "w");

header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
fputcsv($handler, $fields, ';', '"');

fclose($handler);
```

Note `php://output` is a write-only stream that allows you to write to the output buffer mechanism in the same way as print() and echo().

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much in CSV files, but you should try these two things:

1. Put the euro symbol directly.

   **or**
2. Look for the CSV file encoding.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
//add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel
fputs($fp, $bom =( chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF) ));
fputcsv($handler, $fields, ';', '"');
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried  to use `&#128;` for € , instead of `&euro;` ?

Comment: Have you tried `&#128;`? It's a [**control**](https://old.unicode-table.com/en/0080/)  (unprintable U+0080,  *Padding Character*). Euro sign is [another character](https://old.unicode-table.com/en/20AC/).

Comment: I wrote this response 11 years ago. In those days &#128; inde decimals  meant € . Try it in google before you downwote me. https://www.codetable.net/decimal/128