# Html entities of Euro symbol showing in AJAX response instead of actual Euro symbol - getting &euro; instead of €

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html-entities

I am doing an AJAX call and in the AJAX handler code (PHP side) I have to return a string containing the currency symbol. I have `&euro;` to begin with in the PHP side, which I try to encode using `html_entity_decode()` but I am getting `&euro;` when I alert the response in the javascript part.

I did `html_entity_decode()` of the value before returning the AJAX response in PHP -

```
$currency = "&euro;"; //I am getting this from somewhere so I cannot change it. 
echo json_encode(array("message" => htmlentity_decode($currency)));
```

But still it shows `&euro;` when I alert using javascript.

Even when I look at the firebug console, it shows  `&euro;`.

I also checked that in non-AJAX case, for a normal PHP page, if I echo the following, I get `€` as expected -

```
$currency = "&euro;";
htmlentity_decode($currency);
```

So, What am I missing here. Do I need to set some character related stuff using header()? I tried this -

`header("Content-Type: charset=UTF-8;");`

I also checked [Html entities like &euro; is not converted to its symbol in CSV conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722709/html-entities-like-euro-is-not-converted-to-its-symbol-in-csv-conversion)

**Update**

*Note: I tried setting $currency = "€" but that sets the "message" attribute of the response null. The response in the firebug console output shows this -*

```
{"message":null}
```

**Update 2**

I use jQuery.

*What I do with the response?*

I just display the response in a confirmation message like this -

```
if(confirm(res.message)){alert("confirmed")}. //this renders html entities (&euro;), I want this to render €
```

I checked that if I append the response to something in the UI, the Euro symbol € appears - `$('.jqModal').append(res.message);`

Comment: are you sure you got `€`? Did you check the 'source' of the browser page you viewed that in? REmember browsers will lie to you and render entities, not show their raw content when in html mode.

Comment: @Mark, yes I verified from source that I get `€` for a normal PHP page (non-AJAX case).

Comment: This is just an idea: are you using jQuery? Because jQuery has some methods (e.g. [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) that will convert special chars to their html entities.

Comment: what do you do with the response? if it added with `.innerHTML` (`.html()` in jQuery) it suppose to work (and you don't need any `htmlentity_decode` or anything like that, with `.innerText` (`.text()` in jQuery) it will show the exact text

Comment: @Carsten yes I use jQuery.

Comment: @YaronU - I just display the response in a confirmation message like this - `if(confirm(res.message)){alert("confirmed")}`. I checked that if I append the response to something in the UI, the Euro symbol `€` appears -  `$('.jqModal').append(res.message);`

Comment: @SandeepanNath you alert it for test purposes or because you need to alert it in production? the content of the alert box is not HTML - therefore - it is not rendered as euro symbol, but if you use it as html (like you say with the `append` it should work fine - and as you say it is)

Comment: We need to alert it in production (not test purpose :( )...

Comment: I checked that by not making any changes in PHP side and explicitly decoding the HTML entities the javascript side, after receiving response, the problem gets fixed. I added this javascript function `html_entity_decode()` (http://phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode/) and called it before alerting the response, but that too did not work (then I added support for Euro in that function) and now it works..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked that by not making any changes in PHP side and explicitly decoding the HTML entities in the javascript side, after receiving response, the problem gets fixed. I added this javascript function `html_entity_decode()` (phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode) and called it before alerting the response, but that too did not work (then I added support for Euro in that function) and now it works..

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with the `htmlentity_decode($currency)` part, but with the `json_encode` part. This will turn your euro symbol back to an htmlentity.

You could use `json_encode($currency, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` to force the use of the actual € symbol, but personally I think you are better of with sending the html entity. As some browser will see that as invalid code and you'll get unexpected results.

Comment: I checked that by not making any changes in PHP side and explicitly decoding the HTML entities the javascript side, after receiving response, the problem gets fixed. I added this javascript function `html_entity_decode()` (phpjs.org/functions/html_entity_decode) and called it before alerting the response, but that too did not work (then I added support for Euro in that function) and now it works..